# Harmonic analysis in number theory

Tags: analysis, number-theory, harmonic-analysis, career-development

When I was reading Folland's [A course in abstract harmonic analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0849384907), I was told these materials have wonderful applications to number theory. However, I do not see really a lot of examples there.

Can someone give some references on the applications of harmonic analysis to number theory?

I am asking this question because I am trying to figure out what to do in my coming graduate years. I have learnt a lot analysis but I do not really like doing hard analysis all day, so maybe some application of analysis to other parts of mathematics suits me better.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Fourier analysis on number fields is relevant to $L$-functions for instance.

Comment: I have only skimmed over it, but "Fourier Analysis on Number Fields" by Ramakrishnan and Valenza looks worth checking out.

Answer (score 4):

Hugh L. Montgomery, [Ten Lectures](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=CBMS-84) on the Interface between Analytic Number Theory and Harmonic Analysis.

Comment: Too bad I don't have access to this. But thanks anyway!

Comment: If you have access to a library, maybe they can get it for you on interlibrary loan.